# If the sum of a set of numbers is bigger, will the average of the set of numbers be bigger too?

Tags: statistics, arithmetic-progressions

If the sum of a set of real numbers $X$ is bigger than the sum of a set of numbers $Y$, will the average of $X$ be bigger than $Y$ and vice versa?

What is a proof either way?

Comment: That depends how many numbers are in each set. If one set has a different amount of numbers then the other set, then no conclusion can be drawn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in fact asking if

$$a>b\implies \frac ac>\frac bd$$ for some numbers $a,b,c,d$ (in your case $c,d$ are integers, but that does not change much).

This clearly does not hold, unless $c=d$.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out whether to represent cumulative payoffs as an aggregate or as an average. Individual payoffs are between 0 and 1, so it would be very useful to me if I represented a person's cumulative payoff as the average of all their individual payoffs between 0 and 1. But your answer suggests that could lead to very very different results, so I can't normalize it like that. I'm not sure what to do. What do you suggest?

Comment: @histrionics: payoffs between $0$ and $1$ ? Do you mean $\$$ ??

Comment: It's not exactly \$, more abstract social payoff. But still it's similar to $. I want a function that is linear in a person's cumulative payoffs, but if I use aggregation then payoffs can sum to anywhere from little -923 to 0 to big like 8374, so I wanted a way to normalize it between 0 and 1. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the benefit of normalization, other than dropping information ?

Comment: Scale, I want all updates to be on the same scale, but without normalization the updates can have very different magnitudes.

Comment: You said from -923 to 8374. If the normalization is the same for all, what does that change ?

Comment: That was just example, there is no limit.

Answer (score 2):

$2+6>7$ but $(2+6)/2<7/1=7.$